# Combining multiple rows according to specific value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, coding-style, ssms

I am running a query and am getting the following table as a result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvxPM.jpg

Regarding this output I was wondering what would be the easiest way to do the following:
1)  Group the rows from each quarter with the really small percentages that add up to 1% as Misc. and then delete the rows that were grouped from the table
2)  Concatenating the orgType and terrName columns to get one column

I was thinking of going the route of creating another temp table and inserting the data into those rows until a specific sum was reached and then just inserting Misc. along with the difference but I think this solution is messy and would probably be prone to errors.

Comment: If you downvote this please do comment why so that I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Here are some things to note - give sample tables and rows, code you tried, expected and actual output, errors you faced etc. Without this, its generally impossible to help anyone. Its so obvious, but many people just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a lot easier than I expected; K.I.S.S would apply here.

The initial table structure that was being output is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #terrDivision
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    quartNYear nvarchar (14),
    orgType nvarchar(30),
    terrName nvarchar(1024),
    IncidsInTerr INT,
    percentOfTotal FLOAT
)
```

To group the percentOfTotal < 1 I used this

```
SELECT MAX(RowId) AS RowId, quartNYear, orgType, CASE WHEN percentOfTotal < 1.0 THEN 'Misc.' ELSE terrName END AS TerrName,
              SUM(IncidsInTerr) AS IncidsInTerr, SUM(percentOfTotal) AS PercentOfTotal
FROM   #terrDivision 
GROUP BY quartNYear, orgType, CASE WHEN percentOfTotal < 1.0 THEN 'Misc.' ELSE terrName END
ORDER BY quartNYear, orgType, CASE WHEN percentOfTotal < 1.0 THEN 'Misc.' ELSE terrName END
```